# Mac osx Django PIL error / usr/bin/cc file error on re-install

Tags: python, django, macos, python-imaging-library

I am getting the ever famous The _imaging C module is not installed error with a django form Image upload. I am trying to work through the many re-install tuts out there but every time I try to  install pil with either pip install or brew install I get a directory not found error at /usr/bin/cc.

Has anyone ran into this before? Any hints to get me moving in the right direction? I am running everything in a virtual enviroment and would like to continue to do so.

Thanks!!
CG

EDIT:

Installing Xcode fixed my problem, I am now getting the following error:

```
WARNING: '' not a valid package name; please use only.-separated package names in setup.py
--- using frameworks at /System/Library/Frameworks
unable to execute gcc-4.0: No such file or directory
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'gcc-4.0' failed with exit status 1
```

Comment: Have you installed Mac OS X Developer Tools? Probably there is a c compiler on you system, just in an unexpected location for PIL. A candidate would be `/Developer/usr/bin/cc`.

Comment: I have installed developer tools, but I am not sure what I should do to instruct PIL to use this... Let me look through my files and see what I find. Can I copy the file to the other location or will chaos ensue if I do so.

Comment: pip install is also throwing the gcc error. From what I have seen so far it seems that xcode should have installed gcc, but it appears that is not the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you *sure* you totally installed the Developer Tools?  On Mac OS X 10.7 Lion, when you get Xcode 4.1 from the Mac App Store, it downloads an installer into `/Applications`.  You then have to manually run that installer.  That will add the expected links for `/usr/bin/cc` and other tools.

Comment: I just updated to lion, maybe the cat went wild and broke something in the install. I will download the newest version of Xcode and try to reinstall, looks like it is a pretty big download so it may take a little while. Thank you for the tip.

Comment: If you updated to Lion, you have to download and install the latest Xcode 4.1 for it.  Previous versions of Xcode won't work.  P.S. Don't forget to mark answers as accepted if they help.

Comment: Ok, I will give this a shot and respond appropriately :)

Comment: Well, this was the correct answer to my question.  But of course now I am having another issue:

Comment: In general, you should ask a new question once you've accepted an existing one.  Without more information about exactly what commands you are running to try to install PIL, it's kinda hard to guess what is going on.  However, the 'gcc-4.0' suggests you may have are trying to install PIL with a 32-bit python.org Python (in `/usr/local/bin` perhaps) - these won't work on 10.7 if you need to install a C extension module like PIL does.  Either use one of the system Pythons or update to a 64-bit/32-bit Python 2.7.2 from python.org or using `brew`.

Comment: Thank you Ned, you have been very helpful. I will open a new question.